# Show the subspace of a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> If we consider the set $$\alpha = \{(1, 1, 0),(0, 0, 1),(-2,-2, 3)\} \ {\displaystyle \subset } \ \mathbb{R}^{3}  $$ a)  Find the subspace:  $$\ W =  \{ u \in \mathbb{R}^{3} \mid \ \left \langle \{(1, 1, 0),(0, 0, 1),(-2,-2, 3)\}  \right \rangle \}$$

I understand how to prove a subspace by definition and the "span method", but I don't understand how to use $ u $ here. I was thinking of using $a$, $b$ and $c$ with each vector trying to create a system but I have nothing to match these values to.

Maybe i'm confused. Any hints?

Comment: Hint:  $(-2,-2,3) = -2\cdot (1,1,0)+3\cdot (0,0,1)$

Comment: The definition of $W$ makes no sense.

Comment: What is your original problem exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: sift the sequence of vectors in $α$.

The sifted sequence will have the same span as the original sequence (i.e., $W$), and will be linearly independent, hence a basis of $W$.